# Analogue of fundamental theorem of real surfaces for complex surfaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Is there an analogue of the fundamental theorem of surfaces for complex surfaces?

If I know only differentiable functions $E,F,G,e,f,g$ (coefficients of the first and second fundamental forms) where $e,f,g$ are holomorphic functions,
can I use the equation of Gauss and Codazzi?
If not, is there an analogue for complex surfaces?

Comment: You have a complex surface embedded holomorphically in complex Euclidean 3-space, and you want to determine the surface up to complex affine transformation, with linear part in the complex orthogonal group?

Comment: Have you tried looking over the usual real variable proof and seeing where it might break down? I think it goes through with the same steps.

Comment: No, I don't have a complex surface embedded...I have only E,G,F real differentiable function and e,f,g holomorphic function...what can I do for  see if existe a surface embedded in complex Euclidean 3-space?

Comment: In the real case I can use the fundamental theorem  and solve the sistem with Gauss and Codazzi equation...but in my case what can I do?

Comment: If your $E, F, G$ are not holomorphic functions, then there is a problem. Clearly if you have a holomorphic map of a complex surface to complex Euclidean space, then the holomorphic Riemannian metric on complex Euclidean space (not the Kaehler metric) has holomorphic Gauss--Codazzi equations, so holomorphic $E, F, G$. Do you want a holomorphic map to complex Euclidean space? Are you hoping to use the holomorphic Riemannian metric, or the Kaehler metric?

Comment: In first time thank you for your answer! My problem is: I have E(u,v)=(u+v) the linear and real function.I prove to solve the pde system of Gauss and Codazzi equation for (for isothermal coordinates and E harmonic) where the differentiable function e,f,g and their derivates are unknowns...I find that the e,f,g that solve the system are immaginary function.My question now is: If the solution of the system (with Gauss and Codazzi eq.) is solve but with immaginary function, the fundamental theorem is still valid? Existe a surface embedded in 3-Euclidean complex space?

Comment: Your question suggests that your surface is a complex surface to start with, but your comment suggests otherwise. If you have a real surface, with real analytic but complex valued functions satisfying the Gauss-Codazzi equations, then it arises as a totally real surface inside a complex surface holomorphically embedded into complex Euclidean space with the flat holomorphic Riemannian metric, using the usual proof (see standard surface geometry textbooks) but with complex analytic functions. If your functions are not real analytic, then it could be tricky.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand..I don't know what you mean.

Comment: I don't have a real surface, I have only the function E(u,v)=u+v and the function e,f,g that solve the pde system of Gauss and Codazzi equation, are imaginary function..my question is being that solve the system, are E(u,v), e,f,g the coefficient of first and second foundamental form (rispectively) of some embedded surface?

Comment: Even the usual theory for real surfaces only guarantees immersion, not embedding. But are your functions $E, F, G$ real analytic? You seem to say that you know $E(u,v)=u+v$, but do you know $F$ and $G$, or at least know if they are real analytic? You said that you know that $e,f,g$ are holomorphic, but sure you mean that they are real analytic, since you are working with real variables $u,v$, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes you understand correctly...E=G=u+v and F=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any complex-valued real analytic functions $E,F,G,e,f,g$ of real variables $u,v$ satisfying the Gauss--Codazzi equations, there is a real analytic immersion of the set of points where $EG-F^2 \ne 0$ to a complex surface inside 3-dimensional complex Euclidean space inducing the first fundamental form $E \, du^2 + 2F \, du \, dv + G \, dv^2$ with second fundamental form $e \, du^2 + 2f \, du \, dv + g \, dv^2$. The immersion is unique up to complex affine transformation with linear part in the complex orthogonal group. The proof is identical to the usual proof, after complexification of the functions, as the standard proof only uses the Frobenius theorem, which has the obvious generalization to the complex analytic category. I doubt if this immersion will be of any use to you.

Comment: Only one thing...E(u,v)=G(u,v), F=0 are real functions of real variables, but e,f,g are functions of real variables but imaginary value.Its still correct your answer?